# Bootstrap 5 Sidebar Sticky and Overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, bootstrap-5, sticky

I am using Bootstarp 5. Can anyone show me the layout template?

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3">This is side bar</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">This is titles of contents</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-9 order-lg-first">This is main content</div>
    </div></div></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

In PC, there should be a sidebar in left side of screen and main content in middle and titles of content in right side. In these 3 div, each of them have individual height according to their contents. So, when one is scrolled, the other must not scroll with them. Similar to what Bootstrap uses in its offical website. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: use bootstrap5 dashboard example source code and add another side menu by changing two cols to three cols...https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/dashboard/

Comment: Thanks you @atomankion. I read some css of your example. It uses position: fixed; top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0. Was that the underline of making a sidebar here? I want to use a scrollable sidebar and learn how to do it too. Also, thank you. Reading that css makes me learn new thing. I can set css height to 'calc(100vh - 48px)'. That was awesome.